# How to check if SugarORM is already initialized?

Tags: android, sugarorm

Is there any way to check whether the sugar ORM is initialized or not?

Comment: When you extend SugarApp, it initializes and you don't need to check the state.

Comment: @OzgurGUL.... actually, I am not extending SugarApp I am using 'SugarContext.init(context)' to init SugarORM

Comment: Why do you need callback of init process?

Comment: I don't need callbacks i just wants to know if sugar orm is initialized or not by checking something like ....if(SugarORM.isInitialized()){//So that i can reinitialize if required}....Currently i am receiveing some gcm .....on message receive i am saving some data into sqlite....but sometime it shows SugarOrm is not initialiazed properly